# Script Jquery doesn`t work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.image1').hover(function()
    {
        $('.image1 p').removeClass('hide');

    },
    function()
    {
        $('.image1 p').addClass('hide');        
    });
});
```

This is code HTML:

```
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="wrap1">
<div class="image1"><p>This is some text<p></div>
<div class="image2">This is some text</div>
<div class="image3">This is some text</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Code CSS:

```
.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

When the user puts the arrow on the first picture ... I want the text to appear. When removing the arrow on the image text disappear.

What is wrong at this code?
This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=10

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Now it works but all other moving images .. and I want to remain fixed

Comment: If you don't want to hide the text completely then you can always use a CSS/jQuery mixture : http://jsfiddle.net/896280a9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I will assume you are trying to simply have text appear on hovering over an image?

If so try this....

html:

```
<a href="#" class="wrapper">
    <span class="text">
        This is text
    </span>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
</a>
```

css...

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#f00;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: @Diaconescu - two lines of jQuery...check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29131118/4279440)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix you markup as following (close all p tag):

```
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap1">
   <div class="image1"><p>This is some text</p></div>
   <div class="image2"><p>This is some text</p></div>
   <div class="image3"><p>This is some text</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use pure css you can do the following :

```
.image1:hover p {
    display: block;
 }
```

If you want to use JQuery try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.image1', '.wrap').hover(function() { // on mouse enter
     $(this).find("p").removeClass('hide'); 
 },
 function() { // on mouse leave        
   $(this).find("p").addClass('hide');       
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do this with pure CSS.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap1">
        <div class="image image1"><p>This is some text</p></div>
        <div class="image image2"><p>This is some text</p></div>
        <div class="image image3"><p>This is some text</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

.image { width:100px; height:100px; background:#ccc }
.image p { visibility: hidden; }
.image:hover p { visibility:visible; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Two lines of jQuery. This calls for a simple toggle.

> **EDIT:** made it even simpler with the `fadeToggle()` method.

**jQuery**

```
$('.wrap1').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.image', function () {
    $(this).children().fadeToggle();
});
```

Full demo here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/v09kcz06/4/)